# R-Studio cannot read .txt file

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem that I cannot solve, and it is the following: I am writing a document with R-Studio, but every time I try to run it, the program says to me that there is an error. The error apparently looks like to be linked to the fact that R studio is not able to load a table from a .txt file.

This is what I have done:

1. I opened R-Studio and I set the working directory (with the `setwd()` command) in the folder where the .txt file from which I want to source the table is located;
2. I opened the R-Markdown script file (with .Rmd extension) and I run it ('knit HTML' button);
3. R-Studio gave me the following error:

   Errore in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : oggetto "mydata" non trovato; Calls:  ...     handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

How can I solve this? I cannot figure out why R-Studio  is not able to read the table and load the `data.frame`, while the Console inside R-Studio is.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you knit a document in R-Studio, this happens in a separate environment. This means that variables that are available while you type in the console are not available when you knit a document. Similarly, when you set the working directory in the console, this has no effect on knitting a document.

So the solution to your problem could be to simply add the `setwd()` command to your .Rmd file.

Answer (score 0):

In your R Markdown file, you have to specify the path to the `txt` file relative to the location of the `Rmd` file.